# Change of variable in biharmonic equation

Tags: polynomials

I'm currently studying how to derive Michelle's Solution for plane elasticity in the cylindrical coordinate system.

I have stumbled for days to understand how the following equation:

$f''''+\frac{2}{r}f'''-\frac{1-2b^2}{r^2}f''+\frac{1-2b^2}{r^3}f'+\frac{b^2(4+b^2)}{r^4}f=0$

with $f'=\partial f/\partial r$

Can be reduced to the following ordinary differential equation:

$F''''-4F'''+(4+2b^2)F''-4b^2F'+b^2(4+b^2)F=0$

with $F' = df/dt$

Using the change of variable technique: $r = e^t$

Thanks in advance !! Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

$r = \rm e^{t} \Rightarrow t = \log r $,  which gives $\frac{dt}{dr} = \frac{1}{r}$

Now come to

$f^{\prime} = \frac{df}{dr} = \frac{df}{dt}\cdot\frac{dt}{dr} = \frac{1}{r}\cdot\frac{dF}{dt} = {\rm e^{-t}}\cdot \frac{dF}{dt}$

Repeat this process for second derivative and so on.